# Why am I getting deadlock with dispatch_once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

Why am I deadlocking?

```
- (void)foo
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        [self foo];

    });

    // whatever...
}
```

I expect `foo` to be executed twice on first call.

Comment: Seems to be a recursive method without any break condition, don't do it!

Comment: why u needed to call foo twice?

Comment: WHY dod you want to call it recursive?!?!?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Neither of the existing answers are quite accurate (one is dead wrong, the other is a bit misleading and misses some critical details). First, let's go [right to the source](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-228.23/src/once.c):

```
void
dispatch_once_f(dispatch_once_t *val, void *ctxt, dispatch_function_t func)
{
    struct _dispatch_once_waiter_s * volatile *vval =
            (struct _dispatch_once_waiter_s**)val;
    struct _dispatch_once_waiter_s dow = { NULL, 0 };
    struct _dispatch_once_waiter_s *tail, *tmp;
    _dispatch_thread_semaphore_t sema;

    if (dispatch_atomic_cmpxchg(vval, NULL, &dow)) {
        dispatch_atomic_acquire_barrier();
        _dispatch_client_callout(ctxt, func);

        dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier();
        //dispatch_atomic_release_barrier(); // assumed contained in above
        tmp = dispatch_atomic_xchg(vval, DISPATCH_ONCE_DONE);
        tail = &dow;
        while (tail != tmp) {
            while (!tmp->dow_next) {
                _dispatch_hardware_pause();
            }
            sema = tmp->dow_sema;
            tmp = (struct _dispatch_once_waiter_s*)tmp->dow_next;
            _dispatch_thread_semaphore_signal(sema);
        }
    } else {
        dow.dow_sema = _dispatch_get_thread_semaphore();
        for (;;) {
            tmp = *vval;
            if (tmp == DISPATCH_ONCE_DONE) {
                break;
            }
            dispatch_atomic_store_barrier();
            if (dispatch_atomic_cmpxchg(vval, tmp, &dow)) {
                dow.dow_next = tmp;
                _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait(dow.dow_sema);
            }
        }
        _dispatch_put_thread_semaphore(dow.dow_sema);
    }
}
```

So what really happens is, contrary to the other answers, the `onceToken` is changed from its initial state of `NULL` to point to an address on the stack of the first caller `&dow` (call this caller 1). This happens **before** the block is called. If more callers arrive before the block is completed, they get added to a linked list of waiters, the head of which is contained in `onceToken` until the block completes (call them callers 2..N). After being added to this list, callers 2..N wait on a semaphore for caller 1 to complete execution of the block, at which point caller 1 will walk the linked list signaling the semaphore once for each caller 2..N. At the beginning of that walk, `onceToken` is changed *again* to be `DISPATCH_ONCE_DONE` (which is conveniently defined to be a value that could never be a valid pointer, and therefore could never be the head of a linked list of blocked callers.) Changing it to `DISPATCH_ONCE_DONE` is what makes it cheap for subsequent callers (for the rest of the lifetime of the process) to check the completed state.

So in your case, what's happening is this:

- The first time you call `-foo`, `onceToken` is nil (which is guaranteed by virtue of statics being guaranteed to be initialized to 0), and gets atomically changed to become the head of the linked list of waiters.
- When you call `-foo` recursively from inside the block, your thread is considered to be "a second caller" and a waiter structure, which exists in this new, lower stack frame, is added to the list and then you go to wait on the semaphore.
- The problem here is that this semaphore will never be signaled because in order for it to be signaled, your block would have to finish executing (in the higher stack frame), which now can't happen due to a deadlock.

So, in short, yes, you're deadlocked, and the practical takeaway here is, "don't try to call recursively into a `dispatch_once` block." But the problem is most definitely **NOT** "infinite recursion", and the flag is most definitely not *only* changed after the block completes execution -- changing it *before* the block executes is *exactly* how it knows to make callers 2..N wait for caller 1 to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You could alter code a little, so that the calls are outside the block and there's no deadlock, something like this:

```
- (void)foo
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    BOOL shouldRunTwice = NO;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shouldRunTwice = YES;
    });
    if (shouldRunTwice) {
        [self foo];
    }
    // whatever...
}
```