# How to set UIButton font via appearance proxy in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiappearance

I tried to set the font of `UIButton` via appearance proxy. But it doesn't seem to work. This is what I tried.

`UIButton.appearance().titleFont = UIFont(name: FONT_NAME_DEFAULT, size:20.0)`
`UIButton.appearance().titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: FONT_NAME_DEFAULT, size:20.0)`

How to set `UIButton` font via appearance proxy in iOS 8 ?

**EDIT**: Found in vaberer's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy#comment11915072_9424142): "I'm surprised that UIButton doesn't have any UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR properties, yet conforms to the UIAppearance protocol."

Comment: As of iOS 9 you can use `UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self]).font = ...`

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem with a theme-able app.

### 1. Add this extension

```
// UIButton+TitleLabelFont.swift

import UIKit

extension UIButton {
    var titleLabelFont: UIFont! {
        get { return self.titleLabel?.font }
        set { self.titleLabel?.font = newValue }
    }
}
```

### 2. Then setup the `UIButton` appearance prototype object

```
class Theme {
    static func apply() {
       applyToUIButton()
       // ...
    }

    // It can either theme a specific UIButton instance, or defaults to the appearance proxy (prototype object) by default
    static func applyToUIButton(a: UIButton = UIButton.appearance()) {
       a.titleLabelFont = UIFont(name: FONT_NAME_DEFAULT, size:20.0)
       // other UIButton customizations
    }
}
```

### 3. Drop the theme setup in app delegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Theme.apply()

    // ...

    return true
}
```

If you're preloading stuff (`lazy var` VCs from storyboards) earlier, it may be better to instead of using app delegate setup the theme stuff in an override initializer like so:

```
private var _NSObject__Theme_apply_token: dispatch_once_t = 0

extension NSObject {
    override public class func initialize() {
        super.initialize()
        // see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176219/why-am-i-getting-deadlock-with-dispatch-once
        var shouldRun = false
        dispatch_once(&_NSObject__Theme_apply_token) {
            shouldRun = true
        }
        if shouldRun {
            Theme.apply()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is a great idea, and was all I needed to then use the appearance API in the standard way.

Comment: Not sure this works anymore as it looks like Apple removed the font from the appearance API for UILabel.  Also, I believe you could've just used the 'contained in' version for the label within a UIButton rather than having to use the extension, but again, that won't work now either.

Answer (score 3):

Barry's answer works great but the UIButton extension implementation is out of date - you need declare `var titleLabelFont` like:

```
@objc dynamic var titleLabelFont: UIFont! {
    get { return self.titleLabel?.font }
    set { self.titleLabel?.font = newValue }
  }
```

See full implementation here: http://blog.iseinc.biz/use-uiappearance-create-ios-app-themes

Comment: I tried Barry's solution (without the `NSObject` extension), and it did not work.  Adding `@objc dynamic` was the key to making it work.

Answer (score 1):

Set the UIButton's font with UIAppearance as follows:

```swift
label = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self])
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
```

You may add the above code in your AppDelegate's method `application(_:,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, or wherever it is appropriate to set the theme for your application.

In `UIViewController.viewDidLoad` set `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` property of the button instance's `titleLabel` to true.

```swift
class ExampleVC: UIViewController

    @IBOutlet weak var btnOkay: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnOkay.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set a font of `UILabel` inside `UIButton`. Since `UILabel` is not tagged with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. You can't do it like this.

Look at the list of the UIAppearance elements at: [What properties can I set via an UIAppearance proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy)

Comment: Found in your link: "I'm surprised that UIButton doesn't have any UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR properties, yet conforms to the UIAppearance protocol. Is this an oversight by Apple?"

Comment: Yes, but since titleLabel property return optional UILabel, you need to look at UILabel's appearance.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply it to the label when contained in a button:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self])
  .font = .systemFont(ofSize: 19, weight: .medium)
```

Comment: This might sound weird, but set the font size to 17 in storyboard and it should kick in. Seems to be a magic default number or bug.