# How to change UIButton titlelabel fonts style and size in appearance()?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiappearance

I am using the code below but it's not working. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

```
UIButton.appearance().titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20.0)
```

Comment: Hi @MuhammadTayyab, welcome to stack overflow. What is not working? What error messages are you getting? (eyeballing the optional there as a potential source of super fun times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try this instead:

Go to the AppDelegate and paste this-

```
    extension UIButton {
    @objc dynamic var titleLabelFont: UIFont! {
        get { return self.titleLabel?.font }
        set { self.titleLabel?.font = newValue }
    }
}


class Theme {

    static func apply() {
        applyToUIButton()
        // ...
    }

    // It can either theme a specific UIButton instance, or defaults to the appearance proxy (prototype object) by default
    static func applyToUIButton(a: UIButton = UIButton.appearance()) {
        a.titleLabelFont = UIFont(name: "Courier", size:20.0)

        // other UIButton customizations
    }
}
```

And then add "Theme.apply()" here (still in the AppDelegate):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    Theme.apply() // ADD THIS
    return true
}
```

I did it with Courier font and it worked for me. I think you need to make sure your font is installed in your app.

This is where I got it from: [How to set UIButton font via appearance proxy in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862179/how-to-set-uibutton-font-via-appearance-proxy-in-ios-8)

Comment: Thank you Curtain Call LLC. This solution is working for my Work

Comment: @MuhammadTayyab oh awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a font generally, you can call your code `UIButton.appearance().titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 20.0)` in the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` from `AppDelegate`.

Comment: yes I set UIButton ttitleLabel font in AppDelegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: but it's still not working

Comment: Ok I think Apple deprecated the UIAppeance API for changing the font... you can try the Curtain Call LLC's solution, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIButton's font with UIAppearance as follows:

```swift
label = UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIButton.self])
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
```

You may add the above code in your AppDelegate's method `application(_:,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, or wherever it is appropriate to set the theme for your application.

In `UIViewController.viewDidLoad` set `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` property of the button instance's `titleLabel` to true.

```swift
class ExampleVC: UIViewController

    @IBOutlet weak var btnOkay: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnOkay.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}
```